# How can I print a PDF directly from my rails app without human intervention?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, printing

Currently my web app produces a PDF file in the browser and I manually send it to the printer.

I now need to send 100+ variations of the PDF file automatically from my rails app to be printed without human intervention.

How can I do that?

My rails app resides on heroku.  I do have my own local printer, but not sure what my options are.  I researched printers that have an email address, that would be ideal, but wanted other ideas.

Comment: @ Gabe -- I have locally a windows box....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print a PDF from the server, you can use a program that prints to PDF from the command line. On Windows, [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/) will do it. They have a Linux version, but I've only done server-side printing on Windows.

Comment: I suppose she could db:pull from heroku and run locally on a temporary basis. If that's not what you meant, well, I doubt if her cloud hosting service (which is *itself* a cloud application hosted on EC2, BTW) offers printing.

Comment: @DigitalRoss: When she said she had her own local printer, I assumed she was capable of running her Rails app locally -- otherwise why would it matter that her printer was local?

Comment: I mentioned that my printer is local because that's the only current way to print -- but I want to runn my app in the cloud.  One solution i've seen has been email-enabed printers, so jobs can be sent via email, but wanted other options....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know an easy way, some random thoughts...

- since it's your app, you could temporarily run it on your development machine, if there aren't too many technical or legal snags with copying enough of the database to make it work (*$ heroku db:pull*) and then you can probably do something with `system('...')`.
- you could make a single giant pdf that contained each of the variations. This would at least reduce the human intervention to one click.
- you can probably make an ssh tunnel between your app on heroku and your local machine using net/ssh, although I can't think of an easy way to take advantage of this.
- I suppose you could make a quick http-based print server that you run locally (perhaps with a magic auth cookie) and then have your app do client http POSTs to it via net/http or curl or something.
- You could store the pdf's in a table and have a local cron job or something do "heroku db:pull" and then run a script that extracts the pdfs and prints them.

Somehow I don't think any of these are what you want. I think we may need to know more about why human intervention is ruled out in order to focus in on a real solution.

Comment: thanks -- I am trying to streamline and autoomate printing out these merged letters...as the numbers start to go from 10's to 100's, for me to print each one one individual is slow...they also aren't necessary one single big "batch" but done in "drips"....imagine a reverse direct mail drip...does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in rails, but try PHP::PRINT::IPP

Install the class from http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/

Then, in a simple example:

```
<?php
require_once(PrintIPP.php);
$ipp = new PrintIPP();
$ipp->setHost("localhost");
$ipp->setPrinterURI("/printers/epson");
$ipp->setData("./filename.pdf"); // Path to file.
$ipp->printJob();
?>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why everyone is telling Angela how to do server-side printing. Her app is running on a cloud service that is itself hosted on Amazon EC2. I don't think printing from the virtual machine instance is really what she wants, although I suppose one possibility is to temporarily run her app locally.

Comment: @DigitalRoss -- yes, thank you for helping clear my message...yes, it is on heroku / amazon and my machine is local...how can it print, say, while i am away -- i have some tasks running in cron...thank you.

Comment: This is exactly what we need to do. I am surprised that there is no accepted way of doing it. In our case we are going out to Fedex, who return us a PDF. We'd like to immediately print that PDF to the printer attached to the workstation.